# highlight current page link in opencart or any php

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

Im just learning open cart, but I think this question could be answered by anyone with good php knowledge.

I am simply attempting to highlight the a link when only on that page, but it doesnt seem to work

```
<?php $tickets = 'index.php?route=product/category&path=600'; ?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.limerickfc.ie">Limerick FC</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $tickets; ?>" <?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $tickets )) echo "class=\"current\" ";
?>  > Tickets     </a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>" class="current">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know the variable `$tickets` is fine because the link goes to where its supposed to go, and I know the class `current` is fine because it works for the third `li` which is shop.

Am I using `strpos` correctly?

Comment: Lookup strpos. It returns boolean `false` if not found, or the position if found which can still be `0`. Use `strpos(..) !== false` to check if it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`.

```
<a href="<?php echo $tickets; ?>" <?php echo (basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $tickets) ? '"class=\"current\"' : ""; ?>>Tickets</a>
```

it would be more better if you declare `basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` in variable.

Comment: Thank you I used `echo` to see what `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` was giving out and it wasnt giving the actual specific current url.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos()` returns false if the string matches at char 0 - which the above does.

Use indentical comparisons `===` for a true outcome.

As a note, i've used `substr_count()` in the past for similar circumstances without needing identical comparison!